# Twitter::Error::Forbidden: Error creating status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, twitter

I am trying to send tweets from a web job to notify my users of certain events.

It works fine on my local machine but when deployed to Heroku I get the following error when trying to tweet with media:

```
Twitter::Error::Forbidden: Error creating status.
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/twitter-5.17.0/lib/twitter/rest/response/raise_error.rb:12:in `on_complete'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/response.rb:9:in `block in call'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/response.rb:57:in `on_complete'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/response.rb:8:in `call'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/request/url_encoded.rb:15:in `call'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/request/multipart.rb:14:in `call'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/twitter-5.17.0/lib/twitter/rest/request/multipart_with_file.rb:21:in `call'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/rack_builder.rb:139:in `build_response'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/connection.rb:377:in `run_request'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/connection.rb:177:in `post'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/twitter-5.17.0/lib/twitter/rest/request.rb:33:in `perform'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/twitter-5.17.0/lib/twitter/rest/utils.rb:50:in `perform_request'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/twitter-5.17.0/lib/twitter/rest/utils.rb:72:in `perform_request_with_object'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/twitter-5.17.0/lib/twitter/rest/utils.rb:64:in `perform_post_with_object'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/twitter-5.17.0/lib/twitter/rest/tweets.rb:233:in `update_with_media'
```

I can tweet pure text tweets without any errors. Any ideas as to what may be the cause of this?

is there some constraints on Heroku that prevents me from sending the image?

The code sending the tweet looks like this:

```
def send_tweet(company, data)
  file_name = ChartGenerator.build_company_chart(data)
  client.update_with_media(company_tweet_text(company), File.new(file_name))
end

def send_test_tweet
  client.update('Test tweet')
end

def client
  Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
    config.consumer_key        = ENV["TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY"]
    config.consumer_secret     = ENV["TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET"]
    config.access_token        = ENV["TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN"]
    config.access_token_secret = ENV["TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET"]
  end
end
```

`send_test_tweet` works fine on Heroku and locally and `send_tweet` works locally but NOT on Heroku.

I have via console verified that the `ChartGenerator` works as expected on Heroku.

Could there be some Faraday settings needed for production? (I noticed faraday in the stacktrace)

Comment: How does the method for company_tweet_text() look like ?

Comment: It just returns a string with the name of the company and a link.

Comment: Is this all the logs you get from Heroku ? Usually there is more information in the logs. As far as I can tell it should be working. A forbidden message should come with a reason as to why it was revoked. This matches the pattern: client.update_with_media("I'm tweeting with @gem!", File.new("/path/to/media.png")).

Comment: This is the error message I recieve when I trigger the method from the rails console on Heroku

Comment: Well, a Forbidden error means that your request was correct but that the API rejected it. As far as the code goes, it should be ok. Check your developer console on Twitter and make sure it is public and the urls are all correct (not localhost). Some reason why it can be rejected is because your exceed sending limits, App is not public yet, etc. You can read more about the error messages here: https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/response-codes

Comment: We are running into this as well. `update_with_media` worked last week, but today it's throwing an error (even though `update` works). Did you ever come up with a solution?

Comment: It turns out that it was my chart rendering that was causing the error after all. For large data sets it failed to create the media file.